# How can I force a login AND have a 404 page in Catalyst?

Tags: perl, catalyst

I'm currently using an auto routine in `Root.pm` to enforce log in. I now need to 404 any invalid URLs and check the login status only for valid pages.

For example `mysite.com/test_controller/action1` should redirect a new user to `mysite.com/login` (which it currently does). But `mysite.com/test_controller/typo_page` should return a 404 error.

I know I could set up a base for every action of every controller to force the login at the action level, but I expect there is an easier way and I'm just not searching properly.

Is there some way to validate a URL in an auto?

Comment: Allowing a user that's not logged to see what private pages exist is usually a bad thing!

Comment: As ikegami says, it a poor design to ask for login credentials only for valid pages. It lets the evil-minded discover what URLs are valid just by guessing. Your public interface should never provide more information than it must.

Comment: So, we should ignore the SEO guy and redirect all un-logged-in URLs to the login (which is what we're currently doing)?

Comment: There seems to be a bit of [FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt) spreading here. Let's stick to the topic and practice of returning 404 when a page is not found. Most real world sites are going to either have sections that require authentication or actions that require authentication. If you really want to **hide** everything, then make sure it is by design. Not by accident.

Answer (score 2):

The correct action for implementing a 404 is to use `default` in your **Root** controller. This would be the standard if you minted your application with the standard Catalyst helper.

```
sub default :Path {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    $c->response->body( 'Page not found' );
    $c->response->status(404);
}
```

Within the **Root** controller the behavior of this will be that when **all** other actions in **all** of your controllers fail to match then the final `default` in the Root will be used as the action. Not matching **anything** is the definition of a Page not found: 404.

Something you may be missing is that `auto` as with other actions such as `begin` and `end` only come into play with dispatch execution **when the path has been matched**. So `default` exists as a place per controller/route to do *default* actions where something **does not match**. Main point is, in your context, you are not asking someone to authorize just to tell them the URI does not exist.

I am talking in an abridged form here for more reading, see the section on [Built-in special actions](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ETHER/Catalyst-Manual-5.9007/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Intro.pod#Built-in-special-actions) from the Catalyst Manual documentation.

This is what you want and there is no conflict with `auto` in your controller.

Since you say this is what you have then something is wrong in your code. Follow my abridged **minimal** setup for something that just works and compare that with your code.

### Main Context

You should be using Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication, it is well tested and stable. In your main context class you should have at least this.

```
use Catalyst qw/
    Authentication
/;
```

This needs some configuration so we give it some values in the **config** section of this class

```
__PACKAGE__->config(

    'Plugin::Authentication' =>
    {
      default => {
          credential => {
              class => 'Password',
              password_field => 'password',
              password_type => 'clear'
          },

          store => {
              class => 'Minimal',
              users => {
                  guest => {
                      password => 'password',
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    }
);
```

### Root

The Root controller needs two actions for `auto` and `default`. The first will do the authentication checks and `default` will handle anything that does not match. Leaving a basic index action in there for completeness **Note** that we leave the request alone when the **login** URI is requested or the user is already authenticated by returning **true** from this sub.

```
sub auto :Private {
  my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

  if ( $c->request->path =~ /login/ ) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (!$c->user_exists) {

    $c->log->debug('**Root::auto User not found, forwarding to /login');

    $c->response->redirect( $c->uri_for('/login'));

  }

  return 1;

}

sub index :Path :Args(0) {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    $c->response->body( $c->welcome_message );
}

sub default :Path {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    $c->response->body( 'Page not found' );
    $c->response->status(404);
}
```

### Login

In a separate controller ( in this case Login ) define the login an logout actions. In this example we are not going to authenticate, just prove that the `default` action works and that matching still works. So two simple actions.

```
sub login :Path :Args(0) {
  my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

  $c->response->body('Matched AuthTest::Controller::Login in Login.');
}

sub logout :Path(/logout) :Args(0) {
  my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

  $c->logout;

  $c->res->redirect( $c->uri_for('/') );

}
```

### Run Application and Test

You can start the application now. You should have either `-Debug` set in your context class or `CATALYST_DEBUG=1` in environment for now. Start, with something similar:

```
CATALYST_DEBUG=1 plackup -I lib
```

Test with curl

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:5000
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Date: Sun, 09 Feb 2014 20:38:08 GMT
Server: HTTP::Server::PSGI
Location: http://localhost:5000/login
Content-Length: 5483
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Catalyst: 5.90052

$ curl -I http://localhost:5000/blort
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 09 Feb 2014 20:40:12 GMT
Server: HTTP::Server::PSGI
Location: http://localhost:5000/login
Content-Length: 14
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Catalyst: 5.90052

$ curl -I http://localhost:5000/logout
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Date: Sun, 09 Feb 2014 20:40:48 GMT
Server: HTTP::Server::PSGI
Location: http://localhost:5000/
Content-Length: 301
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Catalyst: 5.90052
```

For full completeness test in your browser to follow any other redirects issued.

A more complete example can be found in the [Catalyst Manual Section](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ETHER/Catalyst-Manual-5.9007/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial/05_Authentication.pod#Include-Authentication-and-Session-Plugins) with further information of the [Authentication Plugin](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Plugin-Authentication-0.10023/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/Authentication.pm#EXAMPLE).

Comment: This is what we currently have.  But the auto is still being triggered and redirecting un-authenticated users to login.

Comment: @Nojjy There must be something wrong in your setup. To help you with this I have included all steps on a minimal setup that just works.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/Catalyst-Plugin-Authorization-ACL-0.15/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/Authorization/ACL.pm) module Catalyst::Plugin::Authorization::ACL.
Using it you can configure allowed and denied URL-paths depending on logged user in or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you meant and what you want, but if I understood correctly, try the following:

```
# Root.pm
sub auto :Private {
    ...
    $c->detach('unmatchedURLs') if ( $c->action eq 'unmatchedURLs' ); # chose a more appropiate name if you need
    # do whatever you need to do with your registered URLs
    ...
}

sub unmatchedURLs :Path {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    $c->response->body('Page not found');
    $c->response->status(404);
    # or maybe doing something else for wrong URLs
}
```